# Linux не выключается из crontab

Tags: linux, cron, crontab

Создал задачу в crontab, которая каждый вечер должна выключать ПК.

```
# m    h       dom     mon     dow     command
0      22      *       *       *       shutdown -h now
```

Владелец задачи root, но команда не работает. Как будто-бы вовсе не запускается.

Если вызвать `shutdown -h now` собственноручно, системник успешно выключается.

Почему команда не работает из cron?

Comment: может потому что PATH? /usr/bin/shutdown или что то подобное должно помочь

Comment: `shutdown` требует доступ `root`, которого нет у обычного пользователя. Разбор тут: https://askubuntu.com/a/567964